# The definition of $SK_1$ for an arbitrary ring

Tags: algebraic-groups, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory

Let $R$ be a unitary associative ring. If $R$ is commutative, then one defines $SK_1(R)$ as the quotient $$SK_1(R)=SL(R)/E(R)$$ (Definition 2.8 of http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/pdf/PUBLICACIONSMATEMATIQUES_2000_44_01_01.pdf).

> **Question 1:** Is there a general definition of $SK_1(R)$ in the case when $R$ is
>   not commutative?

I have found a such definition in the literature only in some particular cases (for example, when $R$ is a central division algebra).

When $R$ is a finitely dimensional $K$-algebra ($K$ is a field), I can propose  the following definition. Let $\bar K$ be an algebraic closure of $K$. Then put

$$sk_1(R)=E(\bar K\otimes_K R)\cap GL(R)/E(R).$$

> **Question 2:** Assume
>   $R$ is a commutative finitely dimensional $K$-algebra. Is it true that $$SK_1(R)\cong sk_1(R)?$$

Comment: I can't answer you second question, but in my opinion your proposal has a drawback: it's not a functor. In general you have a map from the group of units to K_1, and you can consider it's quotient. It just happens to be a split mono when the ring is commutative.